# In LWC How to redirect back to case list view page after opening a record creation popup by clicking on 'New' overrided button. LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to override 'New' button for record type selection CASE object, on recordType selection for one of the record type(1 out of 4) i need to open custom LWC component. for 3 remaining record types i need to open standard lightning popups.

I created LWC component for opening record type selection. from that popup i am opening new standard record creation popup. There while clicking on the cancel it is just closing the popup and staying on the record type selection lwc. But i need to redirect to case list view.

Custom LWC for record type selectoin Case object
[image]

[image]

I am opening this standard record creation popup by using below code with returl but while clicking on the cancel button, it is not going back to case list view.

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        "type": "standard__webPage",
       "attributes": {
          "url": str.concat(this.recordTypeId, '&retURL=%2F500%2Fo')
     }
  });
```

Comment: lwc comp is not available for action overrides yet, are you using aura comp for record selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not really use `standard__webPage`.

Instead you can use `standard__objectPage` like below:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: "standard__objectPage",
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: "Account",
            actionName: "new"
        },
        state: {
            nooverride: 1,
            useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
            navigationLocation: 'LIST_VIEW',
            backgroundContext: '/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=00B280000047uEuEAI',
            recordTypeId: '0120K000000TO5KQAW'
        }
    });
```

You can get the `filterName` from using SOQL `SELECT Id, Name, SobjectType FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType='Account'`.

**This will open the new record form (standard form) over list view. So, when its cancelled, directly mentioned list view is shown.**

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas it is working as expected. Is there any way to prepopulate values in some of the fields while opening the new popup ?

Comment: Is there any way to prepopulate values in some of the fields while opening the new popup ?

Comment: I dont think, have to check. However, in force:createRecord, you cn prepopulate

Comment: Hi salesforce-sas, I have added the above code and it is working fine in normal lightning application. but when comes to console app.the record creation popup opening in separate tab. Do you know anything about this

Comment: @salesforce-sas, I'm having a similar requirement, where I just want to close the modal on click of save button. Can you please share the attribute names that I need to set or the document links from where you got know about the different state properties.
My question link - 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284484/avoid-navigation-to-newly-created-record-using-navigationmix

Comment: @salesforce-sas do you know of any documentation or github where I can see all of the properties that can be specified in the state object for this call?

Comment: @VincentIp you can check [pageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

Comment: @salesforce-sas  Thanks.  that's a useful resource, but... question?  In your solution above, you use state parameters useRecordTypeCheck, navigationLocation, backgroundContext, and recordTypeId.  How did you find those parameters?

Comment: @VincentIp you find those in URL for standard navigation. I remember seeing them somewhere in documentation or salesforce developer blog. This was related to passing URL parameters - something like the one released in [Spring 20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm)

Comment: @salesforce-sas Alright, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will not have any control over the popup you are using in Lightning. What i can suggest is use **lightning-record-form** component which enables you to quickly create forms to add, view, or update a record. You can create your own custom modal popup and use **lightning-record-form** in the body. You will have the control on events like :-

1. Onload
2. Onsuccess
3. Oncancel
4. Onerror

> Note:- It accepts the recordType id and respect field-level security
>   and sharing for you, so users see only the data that they have access
>   to.

Read more about them:- [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation)

And a sample custom modal popup example in LWC recipes is here:- [Modal](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/modal/modal.html)